# How open modal from one component into another component in angular?

Tags: angular

i create modal modal component and code my modals in modal.component.html file. i want use this modal in my header.component.html file in header component.

related part of my header.component.html is below:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
  <a class="social-account-profile icon-plus"
     (click)="onButtonClick()"</a>
</div>
```

`onButtonClick` is a method in my header.component.ts like below:

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public router: Router, public authService: AuthService,
              public appGlobal: AppGlobals, public  modal: ModalComponent) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onButtonClick() {
    this.modal.openModal();
  }

}
```

`openModal` is below method in my modal.component.ts file :

```
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('projctModal') projctModal: any;
  openModal() {
    this.projctModal.show();
  }

  constructor(private formvalidation: FormValidation) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

and my modal.component.html file is below:

```
<div mdbModal #projctModal="mdbModal" class="modal fade top " id="projctModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
</div>
```

when i run code i get this error in my chrome console:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
```

how can i fix this ?

Comment: It looks like you are injecting your component directly. Are you trying to build a modal from scratch? If so, there are some key items you are missing or you are not showing them here.

Comment: no i use mdbootstrap modal . if i use modal directly in html file of component i want use it work but i want to specific component that all my modals code in that and call each of them from other html component whenever i need

Answer (score 13):

You need to create a modal service to make it work sample example below.

ModalComponent

```
import { Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit,ViewChild, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import {ModalService} from './modal.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html'
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() id: string;
    private element: any;
     @ViewChild('basicModal') basicModal: ElementRef;


    constructor(private modalService: ModalService, private el: ElementRef) {
        this.element = el.nativeElement;
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        let modal = this;

        // ensure id attribute exists
        if (!this.id) {
            console.error('modal must have an id');
            return;
        }
        // add self (this modal instance) to the modal service so it's accessible from controllers
        this.modalService.add(this);
    }

    // remove self from modal service when directive is destroyed
    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.modalService.remove(this.id);
        this.element.remove();
    }

    // open modal
    open(): void {
        this.basicModal.show();
    }

    // close modal
    close(): void {
        this.basicModal.hide()
    }


}
```

and it's html

```
<div mdbModal #basicModal="mdbModal" class="modal fade right" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myBasicModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-full-height modal-right" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title w-100" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>

        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="basicModal.hide()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
       </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <ng-content></ng-content>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" mdbBtn color="secondary" class="waves-light" aria-label="Close" (click)="basicModal.hide()" mdbWavesEffect>Close</button>
        <button type="button" mdbBtn color="primary" class="relative waves-light" mdbWavesEffect>Save!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Modal Service code as below

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ModalService {

  private modals: any[] = [];

     add(modal: any) {
        this.modals.push(modal);
    }

    remove(id: string) {
        this.modals = this.modals.filter(x => x.id !== id);
    }

    open(id: string) {
        let modal: any = this.modals.filter(x => x.id === id)[0];
        modal.open();
    }

    close(id: string) {
        let modal: any = this.modals.filter(x => x.id === id)[0];
        modal.close();
    }

}
```

ANd in your actual component use it like this

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import {ModalService} from './modal/modal.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
   private bodyText: string;

    constructor(private modalService: ModalService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.bodyText = 'This text can be updated in modal 1';
    }

    openModal(id: string) {
        this.modalService.open(id);
    }

    closeModal(id: string) {
        this.modalService.close(id);
    }


}
```

and its html

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <p>{{bodyText}}</p>
    <button (click)="openModal('custom-modal-1')">Open Modal 1</button>
    <button (click)="openModal('custom-modal-2')">Open Modal 2</button>

</div>


<app-modal id="custom-modal-1">
    <h1>A Custom Modal!</h1>
    <p>Home page text: <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="bodyText" /></p>
    <button (click)="closeModal('custom-modal-1');">Close</button>
</app-modal>

<app-modal id="custom-modal-2">
    <h1>A Custom Modal!</h1>

</app-modal>
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all  in your parent component ...

```
import { NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
constructor(){
  ...
  private modalService: NgbModal,
  ...
}
```

Create a function and call in button click..

```
  callModal() {
    const modalRef = this.modalService.open(ComponentName,
      { size: 'xl', backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false, windowClass:'my-modal' 
      });
  }
```

One important fact must import your modal component in your parent component
..

That's the simplest way to solve this problem....